# Если в переменной пустая строка, как вывести ""

Tags: python, массивы, строки

Вот задание:

> Write a function to split a string and convert it into an array of
> words.

```
Examples (Input ==> Output):
"Robin Singh" ==> ["Robin", "Singh"]
```

Вот мой код:

```
def string_to_array(s):
    return s.split()
```

Это проверочные:

```
test.assert_equals(string_to_array("Robin Singh"), ["Robin", "Singh"])
test.assert_equals(string_to_array("CodeWars"), ["CodeWars"])
test.assert_equals(string_to_array("I love arrays they are my favorite"), ["I", "love", "arrays", "they", "are", "my", "favorite"])
test.assert_equals(string_to_array("1 2 3"), ["1", "2", "3"])
test.assert_equals(string_to_array(""), [""])
```

Почему то на последней проверке с пустой строкой ругается
Help people!

Comment: укажите разделитель. При его наличии разбиение пустой строки будет возвращать список с пустой строкой. В Вашем примере `return s.split(' ')`

Comment: моя благодарность)

Comment: @Evrik ответам место в ответах, а не в комментариях

Comment: `test.assert_equals(string_to_array(""), [])` - так логичнее. В пустой строке сколько слов? Ноль. А в вашем примере в пустой строке есть одно пустое слово. Вы уверены?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у метода `split` явно указать разделитель, то при разборе пустой строки будет возвращаться список, содержащий пустую строку. В Вашем случае код должен выглядеть так

```
def string_to_array(s):
    return s.split(' ')
```

Comment: Однако, если во входных данных будут n разделителей подряд, то появятся n -1 пустых строк.  (Лучше уж сделать функцию, которая удалит из списка все пустые элементы)

Answer (score 0):

Данная функция проверяет, если длина списка больше 0, то мы выводим список, иначе — пустой список

```
def string_to_array(s):
    return s.split() if len(s.split()) > 0 else [""]
```